# The diagonal homomorphism of tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $A$ be a $B$-algebra. Then how to show that the map $A\otimes_{B}A\rightarrow A$ defined by $a\otimes a'\mapsto aa'$ is well defined and is a homomorphism of rings?

I think that every $a\otimes a'$ in $A\otimes_{B}A$ maybe written as $1\otimes aa'$.

Comment: Your final line is definitely not correct. Try to start from the universal property of tensor products.

Comment: To give a specific example. If $B=\mathbb Z, A=\mathbb Z[x],$ then $A\otimes_B A\cong \mathbb Z[x,y].$ So your last statement is not true - it is not true that $x\otimes x=1\otimes x^2.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By universal property of tensor product, it suffices to show that $f: A \times A \to A$
$$f(a,a') = aa'$$
is $B$-bilinear.

We will check bilinearity for first coordinate. For the first coordinate,
$$f(ba_1 + a_2, a') = (ba_1 + a_2)a' = b(a_1a') + a_2a' = bf(a_1, a') + f(a_2, a')$$
Hence $f$ is bilinear for the first coordinate. Bilinearity in the second coordinate can be checked similarly.